# How do I configure an MVC-application to be OAuth-login only

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, steam

I'm trying to configure an MVC 5 application to use Steam login only i.e. no user registration, etc. I'm completely new to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Owin, so I'm struggling a bit to understand what my basic flow should be.

I'm using the `Owin.Security.Providers.Steam` installed via NuGet.

Below I have listed my Startup.Auth.cs and AccountController. You will notice I have implemented custom UserManager and SignInManager along with a custom user store. This part works fine, but when I'm done logging the user in, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` continues to be false. To fix this I've tried to add cookie authentication to my Startup.Auth.cs, but when I do so I get the following exception in my ExternalLoginCallback:

```
Line 79:             var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4098162
Microsoft.Owin.Security.<AuthenticateAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +358
```

This is my Startup.Auth.cs:

```cs
app.CreatePerOwinContext<SteamUserManager>(SteamUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<SteamSignInManager>(SteamSignInManager.Create);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseSteamAuthentication("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); // My Steam key
```

AccountController.cs:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    return ExternalLogin("Steam", returnUrl);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            return await CreateFirstTimeUser(loginInfo, returnUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty straight-forward. AuthenticationType on the CookieAuthenticationOptions should be ApplicationCookie and not ExternalCookie.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a similar thing working with Google, based on the example at http://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/ . My problem is that the Identity on the ControllerContext.User is never being set to the identity returned from `Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo()` The end result is that I'm constantly redirected to `/Account/Login` after the challenge - I'm assuming it's to do with which cookie it uses, but I've tried copying both your cookie settings and the ones from that article, with no success.  Did you encounter anything like this?